# the total price in the datagrid when I passed it round that price

Tags: c#

my English is not good because I'm Spanish so I'm using a translator if you do not understand something ask me.

my problem is that I'm doing a program with two windows in main window I have a datagrid in the second window I pass information with textbox, the problem is that by passing the total price by multiplying the amount I get a dessert for the price of a dessert, the total price in the datagrid when I passed it round that price, if the price happened 1.20 the program will change to 1.

gives me no error so I'll have to spend the entire program code sorry.

This is the second window

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (Application.Current.Properties["seleccionado"] == null)
   {
       textBox1.IsEnabled = false;
       Postresinfo = new TabladePostre();
   }
   else
   {

        Postresinfo = (TabladePostre) (Application.Current.Properties["seleccionado"]);
        textBox1.IsEnabled=false;
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(Postresinfo.refPostre);
        textBox2.Text = Postresinfo.NombrePostre;
        textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(Postresinfo.cantidad);
        textBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(Postresinfo.precio);
        textBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(Postresinfo.preciototal);

    }
    LinqdePostresDataContext BasedeDatos;


    string filename = "";
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
BasedeDatos(LinqdePostresDataContext)Application.Current.Properties["basedeDatos"];

    Postresinfo.NombrePostre = textBox2.Text;
    Postresinfo.cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
    Postresinfo.precio = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox4.Text);
    Postresinfo.preciototal = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox5.Text);
    Postresinfo.imagen = filename;

    if (Application.Current.Properties["seleccionado"] != null)
    {
       Postresinfo.refPostre=Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    }
    else
    {
       BasedeDatos.TabladePostres.InsertOnSubmit(Postresinfo);
    }
        BasedeDatos.SubmitChanges();
        this.Close();

    }
    decimal precio = 0;


    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        precio = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox4.Text);
        textBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(precio * Convert.ToDecimal(textBox3.Text));


    }

    private void button9_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Configure open file dialog box
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".jpg"; // Default file extension
        dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.jpg)|*.jpg"; // Filter files by extension 

        // Show open file dialog box
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        // Process open file dialog box results 
        if (result == true)
        {
            // Open document 
            filename = dlg.FileName;
            ImageSourceConverter conversor = new ImageSourceConverter();
            image1.Source = (ImageSource)conversor.ConvertFromString(filename);
        }
    }
```

this is the main window:

```
LinqdePostresDataContext BasedeDatos = new LinqdePostresDataContext();

private void activar(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

   Cargartabla();
}

private void Cargartabla()
{
   var postre = (from n in BasedeDatos.TabladePostres
                 select n);
    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = postre;
}

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Properties["seleccionado"] = null;
        Ventana2 Ventana2 = new Ventana2();
        Ventana2.Show();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      BasedeDatos.TabladePostres.DeleteOnSubmit((TabladePostre)dataGrid1.SelectedItem);
      BasedeDatos.SubmitChanges();
      Cargartabla();
    }

    private void Activar2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cargartabla();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
   Application.Current.Properties["seleccionado((TabladePostre)dataGrid1.SelectedItem);
        Application.Current.Properties["basedeDatos"] = BasedeDatos;
        Ventana2 ventana2 = new Ventana2();
        ventana2.Show();
    }
```

If you need to know also I have a database with int price, int quantity in the total price in decimal.

thanks for reply, I tried both options have given me but does not work, these are the faults:

Postresinfo.refPostre = float.Parse (textBox1.Text) gives me no errors, the program runs normally and nothing changes

float.TryParse (textBox1.Text, out Postresinfo.refPostre) has these faults:

Error 1 A property, indexer or dynamic member access May not be passed as an out or ref parameter.

Error 2 The best overloaded method match for 'float.TryParse (string, out float)' has some invalid arguments

Error 3 Argument 2: can not convert from 'out int' to 'float out'

I tried the other code and nothing changes, the program runs normally

shane now, I tried this code:

Convert.ToDecimal (textBox1.Text);

but it changes nothing and runs normally.

I've also tried the other code, but nothing changes and the program runs normally

the fault is not textbox1, I think it's because it's in that TextBox5 textbox where I enter the price in decimal and passes it to the datagrid and is the rounded

I'll also attach the column fails me:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=preciototal}" Header="Precio Total"/>
```

[image: datagrid]

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are converting a price like "1.20" to an int with `Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);`.

Try change `Postresinfo.refPostre` to a decimal and use `Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);` so use something like this as a `FormatException` could be thrown:

```
try
{
    Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //Deal with Error
}
```

Comment: still can cause exception. please mention that

Answer (score 0):

you got a lot of code here and i'm not sure what is the problem. i understand that you get round value but it'll be helpful to mention the name of the textBox that it happens in it.

i did saw this code:

```
Postresinfo.refPostre=Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
```

in `button1_Click` which will cause rounding if the value in `textBox1.Text` is float.

you should do

```
Postresinfo.refPostre=float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
```

or

```
float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out Postresinfo.refPostre);
```

because it's a textbox and you might get a value which isn't a number.
if you decide to use `Parse` then you should do

```
try
{
   Postresinfo.refPostre=float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
}
catch
{
   // Show a message or write to log or simething
}
```